# Oracle SQL - How to get the assignment id of the record with the maximum date

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to get the assignment id of the employee who was the last occupant of the position. That would be the last assignment who had the position or the maximum date. How can I retrieve both in the below query?

```
select max(to_char(paaf.effective_start_date, 'yyyymmdd')) || to_char(paaf.assignment_id)
from   apps.per_all_assignments_f paaf
where  paaf.position_id = 159841 
and    paaf.assignment_type in ('E', 'C')
and    paaf.primary_flag = 'Y'
```

I'm converting the maximum date to a character in order to substring it out in the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems like that can easily be solved using a window function:

```
select * 
from (
  select paaf.*, 
         max(paaf.effective_start_date) over (partition by position_id) as max_start_date
  from   apps.per_all_assignments_f paaf
  where  paaf.position_id = 159841 
  and    paaf.assignment_type in ('E', 'C')
  and    paaf.primary_flag = 'Y'  
) t
where effective_start_date = max_start_date;
```

The part `max(paaf.effective_start_date) over (partition by position_id) as max_start_date` is essentially the same as a `max(paaf.effective_start_date) ... group by position_id` but without the need to group the whole result.

As you are only selecting a single `position_id` you *could* use `over ()` instead - but by using `over (partition by position_id)` the query could also be used to retrieve that information for multiple positions.

Comment: This does not give me the assignment_id that the max effective_start_date is for

Comment: @Superdooperhero In what way doesn't it? It gives you the row(s) where the effective_start_date is the highest, and you can then easily just select the columns you're interested in. Perhaps you ought to consider updating your question to provide some sample data and expected output so that people trying to help you can actually run their queries against some actual data, instead of having to guess what you mean.

Comment: @Superdooperhero The query returns the complete row where the `effective_start_date` is the highest for the the given `position_id`. If that row doesn't contain the assignment_id you are looking for you need to provide some sample data (**edit** your question, don't post that information as comments). Ideally as `insert into` statements or as a http://sqlfiddle.com example

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select (paaf.assignment_id)
from   apps.per_all_assignments_f paaf
where  paaf.position_id = 159841 
and    paaf.primary_flag = 'Y'
UNION all
select (paaf.assignment_id)
from   apps.per_all_assignments_f paaf
where paaf.assignment_type in ('E', 'C')
and    paaf.primary_flag = 'Y'
AND paaf.effective_start_date = (select max(paaf.effective_start_date) from   apps.per_all_assignments_f paaf
where paaf.assignment_type in ('E', 'C')
and    paaf.primary_flag = 'Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know, you can't get another value of the row of the result returned by an aggregate function, you need to use a subquery. I think you should do something like:

```
select to_char(paaf.effective_start_date, 'yyyymmdd') || to_char(paaf.assignment_id)
from apps.per_all_assignments_f paaf
where max(to_char(paaf.effective_start_date, 'yyyymmdd')) = 
     (
         select max(to_char(paaf2.effective_start_date, 'yyyymmdd'))
         from   apps.per_all_assignments_f paaf2
         where  paaf2.position_id = 159841 
         and paaf2.assignment_type in ('E', 'C')
         and paaf2.primary_flag = 'Y'
     )
```

Comment: it's wrong because we can get this aggregation via analytic functions `max(to_char(paaf.effective_start_date, 'yyyymmdd')) over (partition by ***)`

Comment: It's also wrong because you can use the [KEEP FIRST/LAST](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm) function to retrieve the corresponding values from other columns for, e.g., the row with the max date.

Comment: This is not a single query

Comment: @Superdooperhero What do you mean it's not a single query? It looks like one to me...

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a single id:

```
SELECT  to_char(effective_start_date, 'yyyymmdd') || to_char(assignment_id)
FROM (
  select effective_start_date,
         assignment_id
  from   apps.per_all_assignments_f
  where  position_id = 159841 
  and    assignment_type in ('E', 'C')
  and    primary_flag = 'Y'
  ORDER BY effective_start_date DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

If you want all the IDs associated with the latest date then:

```
SELECT  to_char(effective_start_date, 'yyyymmdd') || to_char(assignment_id)
FROM (
  select effective_start_date,
         assignment_id,
         RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY effective_start_date DESC ) AS rnk
  from   apps.per_all_assignments_f
  where  position_id = 159841 
  and    assignment_type in ('E', 'C')
  and    primary_flag = 'Y'
  ORDER BY effective_start_date DESC
)
WHERE RNK = 1;
```

Comment: I'm looking for the id that goes with the maximum date

Comment: If you are looking for a singular ID then the option using `ROWNUM` will give that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative, which doesn't need a subquery or an analytic function to find the value you're after:

```
select to_char(max_effective_start_date, 'yyyymmdd') || to_char(max_row_assignment_id)
from   (select max(paaf.effective_start_date) max_effective_start_date,
               max(paaf.assignment_id) keep (dense_rank first order by effective_start_date desc) max_row_assignment_id
        from   apps.per_all_assignments_f paaf
        where  paaf.position_id = 159841 
        and    paaf.assignment_type in ('E', 'C')
        and    paaf.primary_flag = 'Y');
```